# Use seed_fu together with seedbank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord, monkeypatching, seeding

I have been using the [seedbank gem](https://github.com/james2m/seedbank) to give my Rails seeds some structure (i.e. environment specific seed folders, one seed file per model, order dependencies etc.)

Now I came across the [seed_fu gem](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu) which among other things makes it easy and expressive to say "seed these records, and if one with that id exists, update the other fields". E.g:

```
Category.seed(:id,
  { :id => 1, :name => "Food" },
  { :id => 2, :name => "Drink" }
)
```

I can achieve the same result with some cumbersome ActiveRecord calls in my seed files, but I would much rather use the nice syntax provided by seed_fu. Additionally, I want to keep using the features seedbank gives me. Another rationale is that I may migrate only part of my seed files to the other syntax and that it makes no sense to use two rake commands side by side.

If I just put the above code in my `db/seeds/categories.seeds.rb` file and run `rake db:seed:categories` i get the error `undefined method 'seed'`. I guess I would somehow need to import the `seed` method from [`SeedFu:ActiveRecordExtension`](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu/blob/master/lib/seed-fu/active_record_extension.rb), but I don't know how.

I'm on Rails 3.2.13 and using the newest version of seed_fu straight from the github repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: seed_fu and seedbank work together without any problem.

I was using the [zeus gem](https://github.com/burke/zeus) and hadn't reloaded my Rails environment so the seed_fu DSL just wasn't loaded yet.

*(I will leave the question here for anyone wondering if you can use these gems together. TL;DR: yes.)*

Comment: I'm getting into a bad habit of spending ages polishing a question only to answer it myself just minutes later... :|

Comment: You and me both, man. I always say that if it helps even one other person, it's worth the effort.